# Equally sized topics in Latent Dirichlet allocation

Tags: topic-model, lda

I'm using the topicmodels package for R to cluster a big set of short texts (between 10-75 words) into topics. After manually reviewing a few models it seems like there are 20 realtivly stable topics. However, what I find really weird is that they are all roughly the same size! Each topic catches around 5% of tokens and 5% of texts. In terms of the tokens, the smallest topic is 4.5% the largest 5.5%.

Can anybody suggest if this a 'normal' behaviour? This is the code I'm using:

```
ldafitted <- LDA(sentences.tm, k = K, method = "Gibbs",
             control = list(alpha = 0.1, # default is 50/k which would be 2.5.  a lower alpha value places more weight on having each document composed of only a few dominant topics
                            delta = 0.1, # default 0.1 is suggested in Griffiths and Steyvers (2004).
                            estimate.beta = TRUE,
                            verbose = 50, # print every 50th draw to screen
                            seed = 5926696,
                            save = 0,    # can save model every xth iteration
                            iter = 5000, 
                            burnin = 500,
                            thin = 5000, #  every thin iteration is returned for iter iterations. Standard is same as iter
                            best = TRUE)) #only the best draw is returned
```

In short: My question is if there are circumstances under which it is reasonable that Latent Dirichlet allocation will cluster text in topics of equal size? Or is it something I should be worried if it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal, the best explantation I found for it, is from physics. Since Gibbs Sampling was known in physics long before LDA and LDA can simply be seen as a kind of matrix factorization. 
There is a system which has particles (words) and the particles can be in different states (topics). States with lower energy have a higher probability of being occupied than states with higher energy. 
Or simply: Since LDA is a dimensity reduction method that just compresses a words x documents matrix into a topics x documents and a words x topics matrix, the most effective way to do it is by maximizing the entropy which is done if the clusters get equal size. [image]

Just noticed that you can simply derive the above assumption from the dirichlet distribution itself: Take a look at the density (PDF) function and ignore the normalizing factor at the front and only assume symmetric alpha parameter. This results in a product term of X1...XK, that product term gets it's maximum if all X1...XK's have equal size, since the sum X1+X2+...+XK = 1, it's the same case as entropy above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. The question was actually still on my mind, even though I asked it some time ago. Can you provide an article or book mentioning this? What worries me a bit is that I have seen several applications where equally sized topics were not an issue. From your explanation, it seems like topics would almost always have roughly the same size...

Comment: Here you can find the physical explanation and the maximum entropy assumption: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble The topics at least strive to have equal size. Maybe you can find more on this if you look at it from the matrix decomposition perspective: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition QR decomposition looks promising.

Comment: This looks even more promising: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization

Comment: Just noticed that you can simply derive the above assumption from the dirichlet distribution itself:[Link] https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/7d392e761ac5e0ba745945da497d6e007a544778 Take a look at the density (PDF) function and ignore the normalizing factor at the front and only assume symmetric alpha parameter. This results in a product term of X1...XK, that product term gets it's maximum if all X1...XK's have equal size, since the sum X1+X2+...+XK = 1, it's the same case as entropy above.

Comment: Small addition: LDA uses the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution so you have to derive the above statement from it.